# Unable to build using Xcode 4 - The selected run destination is not valid for this action

Tags: cocoa, xcode, xcode4

So I'm horribly confused by this error, other threads on Stack Overflow mention I should set the SDK, but I see no option to do this.  I'm trying to build:http://wafflesoftware.net/shortcut/

And I get no options, and I can only choose My Mac 64-bit, and I want it in 32-bit.  Really beginning to hate Xcode 4.

Here is the screenshot when I try to edit my scheme: http://groovyape.com/scheme.png

Thoughts?

Comment: Xcode 4 seems to have a lot of "teething troubles" - unless you need to publish on the Mac App Store then you're probably better off sticking with 3.2.6 until Xcode 4 has had a chance to mature a little.

Comment: In that case, I don't understand "Build" either, after two years of using Xcode. It's a shame, I was really starting to like Xcode 4 but I'm bailing out like Paul R is saying. I've spend all day trying to work around more and more problems. I had to reinstall Xcode 3 alongside so I could edit my Core Data model, but that made things worse -- I can't compile anything because it keeps complaining about a missing framework even in project that have compiled perfectly for the past two years with said framework. See you in six months, Xcode 4. (Darn, really liked that Subversion commit).

Comment: Is there any reason not to choose "Standard (32/64-bit Intel)? Doesn't that mean the executable will work on 32-bit and 64-bit machines?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Firstly, I have observed that when Xcode 4 decides my Mac is 64 bit and all my other schemes have vanished, a restart of Xcode fixes that.

If you still have the issue after a restart, go to Manage Schemes... (under the Product Menu) and click on Autocreate Schemes now button. Try to delete the other schemes and see if you can run the project now.

However, if the issue is that you need to set the SDK, that's different:

1. Click on the top-level project icon in the left hand panel
2. In the right hand panel that appears, select Build Settings (near the top).
3. Select "All" option (instead of Combined)
4. Ensure Base SDK is set appropriately, like "OS X 10.7".

FWIW I'm seriously considering reverting to Xcode 3.2.5 at the moment, 4 seems horrendously buggy.

Comment: It's definitely still quite buggy and a lot of us were surprised by its release. It also seems decidedly user un-friendly for deployment any way but to-App-Store (you're better off creating a separate scheme and avoiding the Archive action).

Comment: This did work, but I ultimately moved back to 3.2.5.  Really not a fan of XCode 4 right now.  Thanks!

Comment: I had to create a new scheme in order to be able to build again. This answers helped me, thanks. (btw xcode4 is definitly very buggy)

Comment: thank you thank you!  Run and Build were suddenly grayed out and the only way I got them back was by doing "Autocreate schemes".  You're a life saver.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, restarting XCode 4 isn't giving me anything but 64-bit schemes, but I'll keep looking.

Comment: One more time everyone, that's: 

"Click on the _project_ icon in the left hand panel and then in the right hand panel that appears, select _Build Settings_ (it is next to info, on the top)."

As a very very new XCode user, finding "Base SDK" was endlessly frustrating. Thank you for your clear directions!

Comment: Yep, simply restarting worked for me -- got back the iOS settings.

Comment: "Autocreate schemas" did the trick for me,but it's surprising how refactoring the name of a project can mess things up.

Answer (score 9):

In `xCode 4.4.1`, use `Validate Settings` to solve the problem!

I can select either `32bit` or `64bit` now.

Comment: Just had this problem, this is the way to go.

Comment: This helped me today to compile an OS X workspace that was published when OS X 10.7 was the latest. I couldn't run it on OS X 10.11 but now it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Ran into the same error message ("The selected run destination is not valid for this action") when attempting to use XCode 4 to build/run a tiny Objective-C "Hello, World" project I created in XCode 3.x. Fixed it by choosing to "Manage Schemes..." from the drop-down menu to the right of the Stop button, *deleting* the one scheme on the list (click checkbox beside the scheme, then click the "-" button at the bottom left), and then clicking "Autocreate Schemes Now".

I also needed to change the "Base SDK" from 10.5 to 10.6, by clicking on 'folder' icon (beneath the Run button), clicking the root/top of the tree view below it, clicking on the blue icon below "PROJECT" in the pane just to the right, and then finally, choosing "Latest Mac OS X (Mac OS X 10.6)" to the right of that.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue today.  I found switching **Base SDK** from **Latest iOS (4.3)** to **iOS 4.3** fixed everything.

Comment: A lot of the answers to this issue are focused on Mac apps. I had this issue with my iOS app and this answer solved it for me.

Comment: This solved my issue (just with iOS 5.0 instead of 4.3 in the combo box). Could be because my XCode is a bit older, doesn't list 5.1 as a simulator, which is really the latest iOS.

Answer (score 2):

This will happen if XCode believes your mac is a 64-bit machine, when really it's a 32-bit.  If this is the case for you, simply click on your project icon from the far-left pane - it's the menu item that displays your project name next to a little blue icon.  This should bring up a center pane that says "PROJECT" at the top.  Highlight your project name, and the third pane should now show your build settings.  The first item is "Architectures" which will allow you to specify if you are building a 32-bit or 64-bit application.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of amazing that none of the answers here solved the issue for me, but I figured it out. Forget restarting Xcode, or using Autocreate Schemes, still only 64-bit will show up as a valid destination in the scheme.

The correct solution is to change the Architecture for your project. Go to Build Settings (in the root node of your project), and change Architecture to 32-bit Intel, it's right above the Base SDK setting. Destination will instantly switch to "My Mac 32-bit". HTH somebody.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you're trying to run (Cmd-R or run button) the framework (which you can't do - it's not an executable, just a library) rather than simply build it (Cmd-B).

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and maybe it was a coincidence but when I restarted XC4 but this time *didn't* choose to load my project from the popup window that appears on launch - instead choosing it explicitly from the File menu - the issue didn't occur and the build started ok.

On the 3 or 4 occasions I had this error, I had chosen to load the project from the popup window that appears when XC4 first loads.

As I say, I might have just got lucky, but I certainly didn't make any other changes to the projects to 'fix' the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good practice for moving from Xcode 3.2.X to Xcode 4 is, to remove any references to older SDKs (in the case of Mac OS to remove any Base SDK Ref, etc., for Mac OS <= 10.5, in the case of iOS I think you need to remove everything <= 4.3) PRIOR to upgrading to Xcode 4.

I never experienced any problems for new Projects, created in Xcode 4, only for such that where created with Xcode 3.X or 2.X

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4.5. I was trying to compile for 10.6. It seemed to be stuck on 64 bit just because it couldn't find the sdk. I didn't get any message about it not finding the sdk.

I first tried to put in the correct path to /Developer-3.2.6/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk but xcode didn't want to find it there. Then I copied that folder into 4.5 next to the other OSX Platform sdk (new location I think just look in the bundle).

And magically my 32 bit came back.

So my conclusion is that the 32/64 bit option is really dependent on whether xcode can verify the sdk that you're trying to use. Being stuck at 64 while trying to compile for 32 gives the error without notifying you that its first issue is that the sdk can't be found.

Comment: To be precise the location for sdks (for non-ipnone related stuff) is: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by deleting my xcuserdata in my Project file. Not sure how it got corrupt. But it worked for everyone else in the office, deleting the xcuserdata did the trick. I made sure Xcode was closed while doing so. Just for fun, make sure you delete your DerivedData folder for the app, and do a build clean for superstitious folks.

Answer (score 0):

If this happened after you renamed your app, go to `Schemes -> Edit Scheme -> Run <YourApp> -> Info`
**Select the right executable file (YourApp.app)**

Another way is to select `None` as executable and then reselect the `YourApp.app` from your `Debug-iPhoneOS` folder.