# I can't build my project on a new (git) branch with xcode 4. why?

Tags: git, xcode4

I created a new branch of my project and now when I try to build and run it I get this error:

'The selected run destination is not valid for this action.' Why is this? I don't know why but I just plugged in my iphone and now the project will build. Weird.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: error dialog]

It can be because of:

- a missing setting, as illustrated by this [blog post](http://blog.raducojocaru.com/2011/03/22/xcode-4-warning-the-selected-run-destination-is-not-valid-for-this-action/):

[image: Missing setting]

> The problem was fixed regardless of the value I selected in the above list (it worked with 3.0, 4.0, 4.2 or any other value).
>   When I changed the value in that list though, the `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` setting was added to a section in `project.pbxproj` and I was able to run the app on the device.

- an incorrect [SDK setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319251/xcode-4-the-selected-run-destination-is-not-valid-for-this-action). See [this comment](http://blogs.nitobi.com/shazron/2011/05/05/phonegap-xcode-4-template/#comment-815):

> this is an Xcode 4 bug where it changes the platform to Mac OS X after template creation.
>   Close down the project, and launch it again, to fix it.