# Error message when compiling in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation

As of today I can't compile my iOS Xcode project anymore. Immediately a message box pops up saying:

> The run destination iPhone 4.3 Simulator is not valid for Running the scheme 'MyApp'.
>   The scheme 'MyApp' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination iPhone 4.3 Simulator. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode.

I've already played around with various settings in Xcode but nothing helps.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4 - The selected run destination is not valid for this action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319251/xcode-4-the-selected-run-destination-is-not-valid-for-this-action)

Answer (score 12):

Just a wild guess, but did you have a look in your project settings under *Base SDK*? Does it say e.g. Latest iOS (iOS 4.3) ?