# cocoa:Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

The scheme 'PrintingWebView' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination My Mac 64-bit. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode.

[image]

Comment: So, what SDK(s) are your target(s) set to use?

Comment: I do not know how to set up.I want to run the test.

Comment: You can't run anything in this project until you can build it. Select the project object in the Project Navigator, then select each of your targets and look at the target's Build Settings to see what SDK it's set to use. Make sure each target is set to an SDK that you have.

Comment: oh，thanks 。The old version is no way to run !Right

Comment: Just fixed by [THIS POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319251/xcode-4-the-selected-run-destination-is-not-valid-for-this-action).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've met with this problem.
In my case, the following steps can solve it:

your project -> target -> Build Setting

Modify following items: 1.Base SDK ; 2.Architectures ; 3.iOS Deployment Target.

And then clean and build the application.

Comment: answer helped me a lot. thank you.
I also had to change the compiler to "Default Compiler (Apple LLVM compiler 4.1)"

Comment: @biaobiaoqi. Thank you. You were right. i built keycastr application.
![Base SDK ](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eDQz0.png)

Comment: This helped me so much, thank you. I downloaded some example project code from mac-devs and I've spent hours tweaking compiler options and linking sources to try to build it. I feel stupid now though, for something so simple.

Comment: I'd also like to add scrolling down to deployment target and make sure you have your minimum iOS version on there... mine was set to 7.1 and my device was 7.0.3 so I was getting this message.

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple one:

```
Target 
   '---> General 
             '---> Deployment Info  
                          '---> Deployment Target 
                                     '---> Choose Version (Better lower version)
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is right. I was doing one silly mistake, my application was specifically for iPad, and i was mistakenly trying to build on iPhone simulator, and got this error. Make sure, to deploy on relevant device as well.